# CSS Discrepancy for animating svg paths

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying out to animate some SVG paths and there is something I don't understand. I'm using the **same CSS animation to animate 2 different paths** (different length) but they don't finish at the same time. How can make them finish together independently of their length?

That's my code:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 100%;
  stroke-dashoffset: 100%;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#000000">
  <svg>
    <path id="path1" class="path" stroke="#039EE3" stroke-width="1.8" fill="none" d="M10 10 H 190" />
    <path id="path2" class="path" stroke="#039EE3" stroke-width="1.8" fill="none" d="M100 20 H 190 " />
  </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: That's because the percentage is of the viewport and not the length of the path as mentioned here [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset)

Comment: Ah okay thanks a lot! Is there a way to animate 2 paths with different lengths using the same CSS animation ?

Comment: You can't do it in `css` yet, see proposal [here](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/177), you can tho get the length of the path in `js` and style it there. Instead of `animation` you can use `transition` for tweening,

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for your help.